# Safari jerky / flickering on $(window).scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

I'm coming across an issue in Safari - the image flickers or jerks while scrolling, when altering the height of one element and the margin of another on page scroll.

This is working smoothly and as expected so far in Chrome / Firefox (OSX), but you'll see the issue on Safari here:

http://jsfiddle.net/y1Lrnd24/7/

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    var imgHeight = 300;
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var slideHeight = imgHeight - scrollTop;
    var marginTop = scrollTop;

    if (slideHeight > 0) {
        $('.slide').css('height', slideHeight);
        $('#slide-holder').css('paddingTop', marginTop);
    }

});
```

(May be better illustrated in full-screen: https://jsfiddle.net/y1Lrnd24/7/embedded/result/ )

Has anybody any clues? I tried altering marginTop to paddingTop, but this had no effect.

Any help appreciated - hoping this is a quick fix!

Edit: Thought I should add here that this 'bug' is most visible when using the mouse wheel...

Comment: Was any solution found on this?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, looking at the JSfiddle in Safari looks totally normal to me. This makes me suspect something else - any plugins installed in Safari? Have you tried to Reset Safari?

http://osxdaily.com/2014/01/09/fix-safari-problems-mac-reset/

From what I've read, Chrome and Safari use the same/similar rendering engines...kind of sounds if one is working and the other isn't, then it might be an issue with Safari.

Comment: Thanks - this 'bug' is most visible when using the mouse wheel... (and yes, I'm used to Chrome / Safari behaving the same way due to sharing the Webkit rendering engine) - which makes it more puzzling. Have tried resetting Safari.

Comment: Are you on OS Mavericks or Yosemite?

Comment: I'm actually on Lion at the moment, but it's also occurring on Mavericks... I think you're right, it must be a Safari-specific bug. It's happening across the board on Safari only.

Comment: I'm on Yosemite, and it looks totally fine to me. Which is good news, to a point - but users on older systems might see the issue. 

My next susggestion (if you want to pursue it) - there might be a Safari/Webkit specific CSS fix you could implement.